# android.app.Application subclass, onTerminate is not being called

Tags: android

From the documentation for `android.app.Application`:

> Base class for those who need to maintain global application state.

I am using my own subclass to maintain an object that I'm using to query a server. Also from the documentation:

> `onTerminate()` Called when the application is stopping.

However, `onTerminate()` in my class is never called. I press the back button while viewing my main activity, and everything seems to shut down. My main activity's `onDestroy()` method is called and `isFinishing()` returns true, but my `android.app.Application`'s `onTerminate()` method is never called.

Why is this? What am I missing? Is there something that is keeping it open?

Comment: Try using gallery, browser, launch a heavyweight game so that the platform would lack resources. Still not called?

Comment: Try installing a signal handler for SIGKILL from NDK. Not sure if this will work, and you won't be able to do much in it anyway...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This might be related to the fact that although you exit the application, the process for it is still running in the background so that restarting the application would use the same process.

Also the javadocs states not to rely on the onTerminate code to be called.

> Note: never depend on
>        this method being called; in many cases an unneeded application process
>        will simply be killed by the kernel without executing any application
>        code.

Comment: Note that the docs have been updated to be more explicit: this fn will never get called on a production Android device.

Comment: Which is against C++ spec as well, because kill means destructor(s) never get called (same as crash), which for example causes corrupted save-data.

Comment: At least iOS does follow C++ spec (as far as calling destructors is concerned).

Answer (score 5):

```
void onTerminate()
```

This method is for use in emulated process environments.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html